# How to get the StopIteration value on leaving the for loop

Tags: python, for-else, stopiteration

I saw that there are two new features in Python 3:

- `StopIteration` can be given a value by a `return` statement
- `for` loop has the `else` part that is executed when the `StopIteration` happens

Seems that it is reasonable to be able to work with the `StopIteration.value` in the `else` clause, but I cannot find any reference to it.

Comment: I dont think you can get info about the `StopIteration` inside the else clause.